# How to configure to make `__info__` available?

Tags: elixir

My iex code is as follows:

```
    iex(2)> Mirror.Imports.Product                          
    Mirror.Imports.Product
    iex(3)> Mirror.Imports.Product.parse_description("aaaa")
    []
    iex(4)> Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__(:attribute)   
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1    
    
    The following arguments were given to Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1:
    
        # 1
        :attribute
    
    (mirror 0.1.0) Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1
iex(4)> Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__(:function) 
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1    
    
    The following arguments were given to Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1:
    
        # 1
        :function
    
    (mirror 0.1.0) Mirror.Imports.Product.__info__/1
```

The Product code is as follows:

```
defmodule Mirror.Imports.Product do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  def parse_description(description) do

    {:ok, document} = Floki.parse_document(description)

    Floki.find(document, "img")|> Enum.map(fn {_, x,_} -> x end)|> Enum.map(fn [_, {"src", path}] -> path end)|> Enum.map(fn x -> Path.split(x) |> Enum.slice(3, 4) |> Path.join() end)
  end

end
```

How to make `__info__` available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`c:__info__/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#c:__info__/1) callback is implemented by every elixir-defined module, you don't need to do anything particular to make it available.

As you can see in the error message, the problem is not a `UndefinedFunctionError` but a `FunctionClauseError` due to wrong parameters:

- `:function` -> `:functions`
- `:attribute` -> `:attributes`